# Refining SQL query

Tags: sql

My query is returning too much data.  Here is the query, some sample data and a sample of what I'd really like.

```
select sd.ident,sd.suniq, td.testc, td.testuniq, td.subtestc, ts.testscore, ud.metadept, max(ts.takendt)AS testdate
from studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
where ts.suniq =sd.suniq
and td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
and ts.suniq = ud.suniq
and td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
group by sd.suniq, sd.ident, td.testc, td.subtestc, ts.testscore, ud.metadept, ts.takendt, td.testuniq
order by suniq
```

Sample Output

```
ident   suniq   testc   testuniq    subtestc    testscore   metadept    testdate
102201  2001444 ADEPT   2000091 L3  23  NULL    09/01/2006 00:00
102201  2001444 ADEPT   2000092 L4  7   NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
101184  2001532 ADEPT   2000092 L4  5   NULL    09/01/2006 00:00
101184  2001532 ADEPT   2000092 L4  7   NULL    06/01/2006 00:00
101184  2001532 ADEPT   2000092 L4  7   NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
590122  2001950 ADEPT   2000091 L3  22  NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
590122  2001950 ADEPT   2000090 L2  32  NULL    09/01/2006 00:00
141058  2004980 ADEPT   2000089 L1  27  NULL    05/01/2006 00:00
141058  2004980 ADEPT   2000090 L2  28  NULL    01/25/2008 00:00
141058  2004980 ADEPT   2000090 L2  27  NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
```

Wanted Output

```
102201  2001444 ADEPT   2000092 L4  7   NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
101184  2001532 ADEPT   2000092 L4  7   NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
590122  2001950 ADEPT   2000091 L3  22  NULL    06/01/2007 00:00
141058  2004980 ADEPT   2000090 L2  28  NULL    01/25/2008 00:00
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the sample output? Why isn't `testuniq='2000089'` not included in the sample output even though that value is listed in the `IN` clause?

Comment: What is the difference between the sample and wanted?  It looks like you're looking for the row with the latest `testdate` but it could be something different

Comment: Maybe I just can't seem to understand what you want...but...what kind of refining do you want? Do you just want less results? Or is there something special about the 4 results that you want that should be looked for?

Comment: -1 for not explaining what is desired.

Comment: I believe the OP wants only one row per ident. When multiples arise, choose the one with the latest testdate to display and all other with same ident shouldn't be output.

Comment: Thank you Waleed for explaining my needs so clearly!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  You have too many `GROUP BY` criteria, and need aggregates on the remaining fields.  From you desired output they all look like `MAX` values to me:

```
select  sd.ident,
        sd.suniq, 
        td.testc, 
        MAX(td.testuniq) as TestUniq, 
        MAX(td.subtestc) as Subtestc, 
        MAX(ts.testscore) as TestScore, 
        MAX(ud.metadept) as metadept, 
        max(ts.takendt)AS testdate
from studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
where ts.suniq =sd.suniq
and td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
and ts.suniq = ud.suniq
and td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
group by sd.suniq, sd.ident, td.testc,
order by suniq
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what you are after, you are trying to get the most recent (or highest valued) item to display exclusively... have you tried the 'distinct' keyword? If I had a test dataset to try a few queries on I would be able to get you the right answer pretty quick, but pulling it from the top of my head is another story

select distinct sd.ident,sd.suniq, td.testc, td.testuniq, td.subtestc, ts.testscore, ud.metadept, max(ts.takendt)AS testdate
from studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
where ts.suniq =sd.suniq
and td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
and ts.suniq = ud.suniq
and td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
group by sd.suniq, sd.ident, td.testc, td.subtestc, ts.testscore, ud.metadept, ts.takendt, td.testuniq
order by suniq desc

Comment: `DISTINCT` will just get him unique combinations of the fields you specified, which would be all the fields.